# How to redefine 'YTick' (or 'YTickLabel') colorbar's property in Matlab for non-monotonic data?

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I've developed a new R,G,B colormap of 15 entries based on my data. These entries varying in the range `[0.0,1.0]` in a monotonically growing sequence and represent the value of a parameter P to which 15 samples are associated. For instance, 3 pairs (P,sample number) would be `(0.0,266); (0.5,262); (1.0,276)`.

**Problem:** I wish that P appear from red to blue in the colorbar, but that the 'ticks' mark the numbers for the 15 samples.

It's discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349034/matlab-redefine-yticklabel) how to manipulate the colorbar's 'YTickLabel'.

In [this second post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86343-change-amount-of-ticks-on-a-colorbar) from MathWorks , the solution to change the amount of ticks is readily achieved by calling the colorbar handle `cbr` and using `set(cbr,'YTick',20:2:50)` - as discussed therein. However, sounds to me that both ways are fine since the the data are monotonic and with small amount of ticks.

In my case, P grows monotonically, but the sample numbers associated to them do not. Also, there are 15 ticks.

Then, someone has a suggestion on how can I have these 15 tick marks correctly placed and working together with the location 'southoutside' to have the colorbar in the horizontal?

**My attempts are below:** For both cases, colorbar didn't print more than 8 ticks. I had no success with 'YTick' too, since the sample numbers are not monotonic.

1. More "fancy" way:

   ```
   samplex = [ 266, 267, 265, ..., 262, 276 ]; % vector of 15 sample numbers 
   sx = num2str(samplex);
   sx = cellstr(sx);
   hx = colorbar;
   set(hx,'YTickLabel',sx)
   ```
2. Add point by point

   ```
   hx = colorbar;
   set(hx,'YTickLabel',{'266','262',...,'276'})
   ```

**Colormap matrix**: this is my colormap matrix named `CX` in `format short`:

```
CX = 
    0.5397         0         0
    1.0000    0.4603         0
    1.0000    0.5714         0
    0.4603    1.0000    0.5397
    0.4286    1.0000    0.5714
         0    0.9206    1.0000
         0    0.2857    1.0000
         0    0.1905    1.0000
         0    0.1905    1.0000
         0    0.0476    1.0000
         0         0    0.9683
         0         0    0.9683
         0         0    0.9524
         0         0    0.7143
         0         0    0.5079
```

Then, I use

```
cx = colormap(CX); 
axis off; 
set(gcf,'color','None');
```

before the `set` commands quoted in my attempts.

Thank you for any help.

*Remark:* I just need to set up the colorbar and export it to a .pdf afterwards, with no background color, figures or axes. This step is OK. Here is an example figure:

[image: Colorbar with the only 8 entries.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to modify the `Ticks` and `TickLabels` property of the object created by [`colorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html):

For example:

```
CX = [0.539700, 0.000000, 0.000000; ...
1.000000, 0.460300, 0.000000; ...
1.000000, 0.571400, 0.000000; ...
0.460300, 1.000000, 0.539700; ...
0.428600, 1.000000, 0.571400; ...
0.000000, 0.920600, 1.000000; ...
0.000000, 0.285700, 1.000000; ...
0.000000, 0.190500, 1.000000; ...
0.000000, 0.190500, 1.000000; ...
0.000000, 0.047600, 1.000000; ...
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.968300; ...
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.968300; ... 
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.952400; ...
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.714300; ...
0.000000, 0.000000, 0.507900];

cmap = colormap(CX);
cbar = colorbar;
```

Gives us the following:

[image: yay1]

The range of the `colorbar` is dependent on the range of values in the `axes` object the `colorbar` is linked to. For a blank axes we get a colorbar range of `[0, 1]`. For something like `surf(peaks)` we get (roughly) `[-6.5 8.08]`. Ticks outside this range will not be rendered. With this in mind, for a blank axis we can do something like:

```
nticks = 15;
cbar.Ticks = 0:(1/nticks):1;
```

Which gives us:

[image: yay2]

And then we can modify the tick labels accordingly:

```
% Generate Fibonacci sequence, because why not
a = zeros(1, nticks + 1);
a(1) = 1; a(2) = 1;
ii = 3;
while ii <= nticks + 1
    a(ii) = a(ii-2) + a(ii-1);
    ii = ii + 1;
end

cbar.TickLabels = a;
```

Leaving us with:

[image: yay3]

Note, from the documentation for colorbar:

> Tick mark labels, specified as a cell array of strings, a numeric array, or a string

So you're not limited to a numeric vector.

---

Edit: The above assumes R2014b or newer in order to use the [dot notation to access properties of graphics objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html).

For older versions of MATLAB, use [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html):

```
set(cbar, 'Ticks', 0:(1/nticks):1);
set(cbar, 'TickLabels', a);
```

Which produces the same results.

Comment: your solution works to me when I use surf(peaks) to generate the figure, but doesn't work to change only the colorbar, without the figure. I just have the warning message of 'struct overwriting' stemming from the statements `cbar.Ticks`;  `cbar.TickLabels`. The colorbar kept the same. Here is an unsuccessful sequence using your suggestion: `cx = colormap(CX); axis off; set(gcf,'color','None'); hx = colorbar;  hx.Ticks = -1:1`. `cx` stores the colormap `CX` generated by me through a function. All this results in a colorbar with ticks from 1:2:16 and the 15-color scheme as above.

Comment: @opcg what version of MATLAB are you using

Comment: `Ticks` and `TickLabels` return error of `not accessible properties`. In fact, with `set`,  `YTick` and `YTickLabels` make the job. However, this is quite close to my attempts. The marks continue to print only 8 entries at most and, if something like `set(hx,'YTick',-6:8)` is done, the negative values plus `0`, i.e. `-6:0`, are being ignored. As you did, can you reproduce the same `colorbar` without calling `surf(peaks)`? With no specific colormap like my `cx`, the `jet` colormap should appear as default.

Comment: @opcg Without you providing a colormap that reproduces your error I can only work with what is built into MATLAB.

Comment: I can provide the colormap, but I can't expand this discussion to chat so that I add the colormap matrix here. Sorry, but how can I proceed to show it to you?

Comment: @opcg Edit it into your question so everyone can see it.

Comment: In the meantime, I could solve the problem by doing `hx = colorbar; set(hx,'YTick',1:15); set(hx,'YTickLabel',sx);`. This worked similarly to what you explained while specifying `nticks`. Now, I have the 15 labels correctly placed as I wished. One thing more was to dispose the colorbar horizontally. Adding `set(hx,'location','southoutside')` wasn't showing the correct labels. Then, using `XTick`; `XTickLabel` fixed everything - just a remark I'd like to mention. It's done. I believe that the issue can be closed. Thank you for your interest and contribution.